Spark: How to print timestamp column along with timezone?
Have a scenario, where we get the input data from Teradata(SRC) and load it into the spark hive warehouse. We have a timestamp column along with the time zone as below and wanted to see the same while reading through spark SQL and storing it in the dataframe for further ETL calculation. Mainly columns should be in timestamp data type only.
# Input table column values(printing only one column from the Teradata table):
# 9999.12.31 10:15:00+03:00
# 9999.12.31 10:15:00+05:30
# 9999.12.31 10:15:00+03:00
   
df = spark.sql("""select to_timestamp('9999.12.31 10:15:00+03:00', 
                                      "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")""")

# 9999.12.31 10:15:00
# 9999.12.31 10:15:00
# 9999.12.31 10:15:00

Now, we need to print the value along with the time zone. But we need to derive the same in the output processing as the same in the input column.

Do you just want to print the timestamp along with the timezone as it's already showing in the input table column (the +03:00 part)? Could you please clarify the question a bit more?

Yes Corect @Vikas Sharma

Try this:
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC+03")
df = spark.sql(
    """select date_format(to_timestamp('9999.12.31 10:15:00+03:00', 'yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ssVV'), 'yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ssxxx') as ts_with_offset"""
)
df.show(truncate=False)

Output:
+-------------------------+
|ts_with_offset           |
+-------------------------+
|9999.12.31 10:15:00+03:00|
+-------------------------+

One thing is - it is only preserving the +03:00 offset and adjusting the other timezone for this offset. For printing the other offsets as it is you'll have to come up with a workaround for it. Maybe a UDF which dynamically sets the offset values somehow.

@Rocky1989 Let me know if this works for you. Otherwise - once I get time I can try coming up with a workaround to print the other offsets in their original form without the timezone adjustment.
